# Two hard indices questions, (what is power to a power of fraction) and (how is $(2^x)^2 = 4^x $)

Tags: exponentiation

The answer for question 1)
is $2^{3b+6}$

Question 2 I only don't get the $Y^2$ bit

[image]

[image]

Comment: $Y^2=(2^x)^2=2^{(2x)}=(2^2)^x=4^x $

Comment: [This](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) might prove useful when typesetting your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint for the 1st: $\left( 4^{b+2}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}=\left( 2^{2b+4}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}=2^{3b+6}$.